# Glue create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog return empty data

Tags: amazon-s3, etl, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I'm debugging issue which create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog return no data, despite I'm able to view the data through Athena.

The Data Catelog is pointed to S3 folder and there are multiple files with same structure. The file type is csv, delimiter is space " ", consists of two column (string and json string), with no header.

This is CSV format file.
[image]

This is Athena query using crawler generated.
[image]

No result returned from dataframe when debug, any thought?
[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Take a look if you have enabled the **Bookmark** for this job. If you are running it multiple times, you need to reset the Bookmark or disable it.

Other thing to check is the logs. Maybe you can find some AccessDenied, the role that is running the job might have no access to this bucket.